# Image within a div, both have onclick events, can I reverse the bubble?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, carousel, shadowbox

I have an image carousel and shadowbox. I want the user to be able to srcoll through the images, and when they click on the focused one, it opens in shadowbox. Currently the html is something to this extent:

```
<div class="slides">
  <div>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:ShadowboxRun(some parameters); return false;">
       <img src="img.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:ShadowboxRun(some parameters); return false;">
       <img src="img2.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've figured out that I belive the route of all my issues has to do with bubbling. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that the onclick fires before the carousel. What would my best practice be for this?

Thank you

Edit: Forgot to put the main issue. When the user clicked on slide 2 of the carousel it moves the slide and opens the shadowbox with one click. I want the user to be able to click on the slide have it move, and if they click on it again, it opens a shadowbox.

edit2: Fixed my mistake in the original copy of the code

edit3: uploaded my newest version, so here's the link http://hdguitarlesson.com/HDLessonsBeta/ if it helps. Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been racking my brain for hours

Comment: But what is the problem?

Comment: Oh sorry, brain is fried. - edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the onClick() command through jquery on anything so you can simply add a class or id to that image and click that instead.

Comment: edited the original post. This may be the solution. But I am unsure of how to implement it. I am familiar with enough javascript to be dangerous. The carousel I'm using adds class="slideitem" to the nested div. would I modify the js file to append this to the image instead. then stop bubbling once the function finished?

Comment: Are you using jquery carousel for this?  Generally the links that move the carousel left and right are outside the divs instead of inside.

Comment: it's a redone jquery carousel. the navigation links are outside, and the mousewheel works, but it also allows you to click on the image to change it. I added the link to my site in the orgininal post

Comment: OK i think I understand what you are saying.  You need to distinguish the focused div from the others.  You could add a remove classes from the onClick function so that when the focused div comes to play it will not use the onclick.  Also you can take the onclick command from the a href and put it into a function instead using jquery onclick.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".whatever-class").click(function(){
        //add code here
    });
});

Comment: If you have the full code or want to message me I can help you with this.

Comment: It's like you read my mind. I have a plan, I just don't know wnough about javascript to execute it. I was thinking I could add a class to the front image, that way I could distinguish it from the rest. then have onClick call a function that checks if the user clicked the front image or not. if not, run the carousel if they did click the front image pop up shadowbox. At this point I really don't know if I'm overthinking it. lol.

Comment: If you want post your full code and I can take a look at this.  I had to do something similar and what I did was gave each div a class like "div-one" and then increment a value in the javascript for each div.  So you know that div on the value would return 1 etc.  From here you can strip the class from the div and add an active class to the div corresponding with that value.  Its hard to explain through text.

Comment: I have the link in the original post. How would be the best way to show you the full code

Comment: I did it! and you were right. My code isn't pretty but, basically: in the carousel part whenever it switches images it sets the class on the link to current. Then onclick I have it going to a function which evaluates if the link has class current. If it's not then it won't run the shadowbox function.